# PyCharm & Vim in the same time and in the same place

Tags: vim, pycharm

I've seen people working with Vim on PyCharm. I work with PyCharm, and I've never know how to do that. Could anyone be able to tell how can I do that? Do I have to install a new software?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's plugin called [IdeaVim](https://github.com/JetBrains/ideavim) which will provide Vim experience on several IDE, include PyCharm.

> IdeaVim is a Vim emulation plugin for IDEs based on the IntelliJ platform. IdeaVim can be used with IntelliJ IDEA, RubyMine, PyCharm, PhpStorm, WebStorm, AppCode, CLion, DataGrip and Android Studio.

Before download this plugin, make sure you had following items:

- PyCharm version 4.0.0 or higher.
- Have at least one Python interpreter properly installed on your computer. You can download an interpreter from this [page](http://python.org/download/).

#### Download IdeaVim

On the toolbar of the PyCharm main window, press <kbd>Ctrl + Alt + S</kbd> to open the Settings/Preferences dialog, and then click Plugins.

Once you see the list of plugins currently installed on you computer, click the button <kbd>Browse JetBrains plugins</kbd>. PyCharm will shows the contents of the huge JetBrains repository, type the word "vim" in the search field to narrow down the list:

[image]

After installing the plugin, PyCharm restart may necessary to apply a change.

For more information, please consider read following article:

- [GitHub page](https://github.com/JetBrains/ideavim)
- [Official instruction](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PYH/Configuring+PyCharm+to+work+as+a+Vim+editor)

Comment: I've never known that before.... It is pretty useful and powerful!!!